# Azure container app, how remove load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have an azure container app that I want to use as an API server, basically like I would with Azure Functions. I see a lot of reference to the fact that there shouldn't be a need for a Load Balancer, which is "expensive" if no needed.

Sadly, after creating the container app in the portal it also created a couple resources in another resource group without me realizing. I now have 2 public ip address, a network security group and a load balancer name kubernetes.

Can I remove these? Specially the load balancer, since this state I shouldn't need it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/ingress?tabs=bash

I tried removing it, but it says it's being used.

Thanks,

Comment: We don't require to create Azure Load Balancer, public IP address, or any other Azure resources to enable incoming HTTPS requests, when we use ingress
But in this scenario issue may cause because of funcitonApp logic, it may be on different resource group or having dependencies with network [Nsg].

Comment: How do you recommand I go with removing the Load Balancer ? If I try to delete the whole "random" resource group it says it's in use. I can always re-do the whole thing including my container app

Comment: the `MC_` resource group is only created if you bring you own VNET from what i see in the configuration.

Comment: Ended up deleting everything and re-creating them without a VNET and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Tomas said, creating the app with a VNET was the cause